# SQL: How to replace a column with other values based on alphabet?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table and would like to transform it using sqlite3 and don't know how, hopefully someone can help me.

I would like to go from a table:

```
A   B       C   E   F   G   .. X
1   1234    id1 A   B   ..      
1   42332   id2 B   A   ..      
2   50443   id3 A   B   ..      
2   4532    id4 F   D   ..  
3   5000    id5 B   A   ..      
3   3333    id6 B   A   ..
```

to this table:

```
A   B       C           E   F   G   .. X
1   1234    1:1234_A_B  A   B   ..      
1   42332   1:42332_A_B B   A   ..      
2   50443   2:50443_A_B A   B   ..      
2   4532    2:4532_D_F  F   D   ..      
3   5000    3:5000_A_B  B   A   ..      
3   3333    3:3333_A_B  B   A   ..
```

So column C should be colA:colB_col(E or F, depending on alphabet)_col(E or F, depending on alphabet)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? All the information is already in your table. Storing multiple values in a column is bad design.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, why you want to update it, however the below should help you.

```
select A,B,A || ':' || B || '_' || 
case 
    when E < F
    then 
         E || '_' || F
    else 
         F || '_' || E
    end
 ... -- rest of the fields
from table_name
```

You can use part of the above query to create an update `statement` if you want to. Not sure what are the primary keys/unique keys in your table structure, so can't help you there.

Comment: A key is not needed for this UPDATE.